# Dismissing viewController by pressing on tabbar button remain black screen swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a custom **action sheet viewController**. Which is presented modally on the current top view controller. Like this:

```
//MARK: Static Func
    static func initViewController() -> CustomActionSheetViewController {
        let customActionSheetViewController = CustomActionSheetViewController(nibName: "CustomActionSheetViewController", bundle: nil)
        return customActionSheetViewController
    }

    func presentViewController<T: UIViewController>(viewController: T) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let topViewController = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
                viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                topViewController.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

// MARK: UIApplication extensions
extension UIApplication {
    class func getTopViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tab = base as? UITabBarController, let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: selected)
        } else if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

And I am dismissing it like this:

```
@objc func dismissViewController() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let topViewController = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
               topViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        }
    }
```

It's working perfectly fine. I have added the notification observer in my `customTabbarController`, to dismiss the action sheet if user tap on some another `tabbar` button like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
//        print("Selected view controller", viewController)
//        print("index", tabBarController.selectedIndex )
        let tabbarNotiKey = Notification.Name(rawValue: "TabbarNotiKey")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: tabbarNotiKey, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    }
```

The action sheet is right now presenting on `Home tab > Profile (by push) > Action sheet (by modal)`. So if I tap on Home tab again it will dismiss the **action sheet viewController** and come back to Home perfectly. But if I tap on some other tabbar button rather than home and come back home, it shows a black screen. What I am missing here? Any suggestions would be highly appreciable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code calls `dismissViewController()` twice.

1. When you press other tab, it removes the action sheet
2. And then you click home tab and it calls `dismissViewController` again, and now it removes the homescreenVC